# How do I do topmod style loops in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I've had some pretty good luck with edge loops and the loft tools in Blender.

The spin tool is still greek to me.  I'd like source, destination, angle style simplicity comparable to the methods of TopMod.  Maybe someday.

Here's the problem:

[image: Blender Edge Loop vs TopMod]

So, the simple question is, how to do something comparable in Blender?  What would be the best, perhaps, simplest way to go about it?  Is this kind of thing even possible in Blender?  Worth the trouble?  Or not?

I've got the Angle Tool addon.  It doesn't do this kind of curvature.  (speaking of which, perhaps using curves (which seems like a lot of work for the effort)). The "Tube Tool" addon, does "tubes" and nothing else.  Other than those two, there doesn't seem to be anything else out there, that I'm aware of.

If it helps.  Clarification:

[image: Start / Stop Angles]

I'm interested in exploring patterns of symmetry.  Something that TopMod lends itself easily to, both in the undoing as well as the doing.  Mirroring alone won't help with this end.

Elaboration below:

[image: Loops Symmetry]

Not entirely symmetrical, but, you get the general idea.  Full symmetry would take more time.  This with cubes instead of Quad Spheres.

[image: Cubes 4x4 Symmetry (WIP)]

Also, for this example, I'm using 4x4, could just as easily be triangular, 3x3, or 5 - 4 on each side, one in the middle. 4x4 is just one jumping off point.

---

Followup:

Here's more of that last example using Blender.  It's still unfinished. And, it would be awhile as the faces don't line up at the end and have to
be modified, sliding verts and edges, etc.

[image: Cubes 4x4 - Blender WIP2]

Here's five examples I just did from TopMod.  About 15 - 20 minutes total.
Given your suggestions so far, I'm just inclined to think that, right now, it's just not Blender's strong suit.  It is what TopMod was designed for.
Unless someone can show me different, this, just may not have a practical Blender resolution.

The blend file of the TopMod cubes:

https://pasteall.org/blend/9b87b66ca8bd439681a5f53973763f98

[image: Cubes 4x4 - TopMod - x5]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about your question but if you want to do what we see on the top right:

- Create a flat vertical curve, Create a rectangle, give it an *Array* modifier:

[image]

- Twist it with a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Twist* mode (Z axis here):

[image]

- Give it a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

- Bend your curve. Make sure that its normals go in the right direction. Add more array count if necessary:

[image]

- If you need the tip of the curve to stick to a face, first hook it to an empty, then parent the empty to 3 vertices of the face:

[image]

Comment: I know how to do that.  This is about connecting the faces as shown to a similar end.  Nothing I've tried so far does that.  It's not just about the bend.  It's about making a connection from face to face as shown as well.

Comment: so have you tried to parent to empty, then parent the empty to vertices, etc?

Comment: That's what I was thinking of when I said "maybe a curve".  Given that there are at least 3 or more comparable face to face possibilities in this arrangement, it seems like a cumbersome, inefficient way to get it done.  Not that you're wrong, but, is that the only way this can be done?

Comment: could you please edit your initial question and explain more in detail? are your 2 spheres suppose to be animated and the twisted cable is suppose to follow, etc? There is the Spline IK for example...

Comment: Edited.  Does that help?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be completely symmetrical, but is it supposed to be animated? Because creating this shape then symmetrize would be easy in Blender. Also, you can tilt the curve vertices to twist the object

Comment: It's not supposed to be animated.  It just ought to be a simple enough process that it can be done and undone fairly easily.  Same concept triangles, cubes, octahedrons (which twist more easily and accurately).  The goal is an aesthetically (subjective) pleasing to the eye symmetry.

Comment: what about playing with arrays of cubes along curves, you just tilt the curve in Edit mode, when you're glad you apply the modifiers and you symmetrize?

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last few days porting TopMod's handle code to an experimental Blender addon called blender-handle.

https://github.com/nhthn/blender-handle

Installation and usage instructions are in the README. Feel free to use the GitHub issue tracker if you discover bugs.

I've also written a blog post about how to emulate other key features of TopMod in Blender, plus a complete mathematical description of how its handle feature works: https://nathan.ho.name/posts/topmod-and-blender/

Comment: A workable alternative has been developed by Kushiro (for free):  QuickBridge - https://kushiro.gumroad.com/l/qignp / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ror9uXF8PvI / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVZPAflK5h0